# Why is 生活が豊かになる (life becoming more abundant / rich) causing 快適な暮らしなくなる (losing one's comfortable lifestyle)?

Tags: reading-comprehension

In the following passage, I don't quite understand how the highlighted grammar 豊かになればなるほど and the predicate 快適な暮らしがなくなる relate to each other.  That is to say, I don't understand why there's a direct relationship between increasing one's life's abundance and losing one's comfortable life:

> 日本の住民は、長生きすればするほど健康が心配になり、生活が**豊かになればなるほど**、今の**快適な暮らしがなくなって**しまうのではないかと不安で不安でしかたがなくなるのです。

My attempted translation:

> The longer the life of Japanese inhabitants, the longer they get concerned about health, and they get unavoidably more and more anxious about whether it isn't the case that **the more their life becomes abundant**, **the more they lose their now comfortable lives**.

It doesn't make sense to me that losing their comfortable lifestile is correlated to how abundant their life is, but it actually correlates to their aging (長生きすればするほ) itself. I understand that the *concern* of losing one's comfortable way of living grows as one gets older, something like:

生活が豊かになればなるほど、その生活がなくなるのが心配になる。

but I can't really see anything like that statement in the passage above. What am I missing?

Comment: How did you understand 不安で不安でしかたがなくなる?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add my understanding about this bit. Editing

Comment: I tried to add my understanding of the whole sentence but it got extremely convoluted in English that I am not sure if it helps, that's probably why I subconsciously translated only the (in my opinion) relevant parts in the first place.

Comment: That bit happens to be key to understanding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've entirely left out the last part of the sentence as the comment points out.

'The richer their lifestyle grows, the more anxious (不安) they grow that they will lose their comfortable lifestyle.'

今の快適な暮らしがなくなってしまうのではないか - 'Will [we] perhaps lose [our] current comfortable lifestyle?'

と - quote particle

不安で不安で仕方がなくなるのです - '[They] grow helplessly anxious'

Comment: Thank you, so in the end the causality is between 生活豊かになればなるほど and 心配で仕方がなくなる